# Calculate $\epsilon$ for a simulation.

Tags: probability, simulation

The exercise says that there's a course that takes 3 years and the retention tax is affected by an uncertainty that is called $\epsilon_{i}$, and $\epsilon_{i}\sim N\left(0, \frac{0.15^2}{i}\right)$. After that we are supposed to determine the total number of students in the course during the first $20$ years. The "only" thing that I don't understand is how to discover $\epsilon$ and what to do with that... I mean, what's the proposal of knowing $N\left(0,\frac{0.15^2}{i}\right)$?

Thanks in advance.

Note: It is supposed to be done in Python

Comment: You might want to clarify what is "$\epsilon_i \, N(0, \frac{0.15^2}{i})$".

Comment: @deviaanceee I'm sorry, I'm going to edit it. It was supposed to be a  \epsilon ' ~ 'N( , )

Comment: Formatting note: the "distributed as" symbol is \sim

Comment: @obscurans thanks!!